# WordPress Local Development to Deployment with Version Control

Tags: wordpress, deployment, version-control, bitbucket, procedure

What's the best practice to implement the Version Control for WordPress Website Development from localhost to Deployment?

Any way better than this?

1. Setup WordPress using MAMP and install your theme and setup everything
2. Push to Bitbucket
3. Push to Live Servver
4. Export the Local DB and Import to Live Server DB

How about future changes? Maintenance after deployment.

1. Export the DB from live server and import to Local DB?
2. Continue the development?

Answer (score 0):

I just drop some links for tools that i use:

- local development env: http://vagrantpress.org/
- Upload ftp http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp
- git or Bitbucket to ftp http://ftploy.com/

Comment: thanks in advance. But seem like still going through the manual way. Any process like Local --> Bitbucket --> Live Server

Comment: Plus How about the maintenance? What if I install some plugin and the plugin does install some table in DB while the live server DB is constantly update with user's data?